# Updating d3 js to new version not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I updated d3 js **3.5.5 to 5.16.0**. I just needed an arc behind my text. Before upgrade its works fine. After updating to current version it not works as expected. Please assist me If I done anything wrong.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js" ></script>
var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(d3.values(dataset)).enter().append("g");
var path = gs.selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) {
        return pie(d);
    })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i, j) {
      console.log(j)
        if (i == 0 && j == 0)
          return '#f37123';
        if (i == 0 && j == 1)
          return '#feb914';
        if (i == 0 && j == 2)
          return '#fef538';
        else
          return '#f37123';
    })
    .attr("d", function(d, i, j) {
        if (j == 0) {
            return arc.innerRadius(20 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(10 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
        } else if (j == 1) {
            return arc.innerRadius(12 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(1 + cwidth * (j + 1))(d);
        }  else if (j == 2) {
            return arc.innerRadius(3 + cwidth * j).outerRadius(7 + cwidth * (j))(d);
        }else{
          alert('sd')
          return arc(d);
        }
    })
```

[Actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOAFD.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYidV.png)

Please assist me